# Запятая или незапятая?

Tags: запятые

Правда, что запятая эта необязательна, но, как я и пишу, значение разное?

> Я недоварил бобы потому, что, когда мягки. Наверное, они стали тверды после того, как вода **слилась и температура** стала ниже. (Я недоварил бобы потому, что, когда я их пробнул, они были мягки. Наверное, они стали тверды после того, как вода слилась, и после того, как температура стала ниже.)

> Я недоварил бобы потому, что, когда я их пробнул, они были мягки. Наверное, они стали тверды после того, как вода **слилась, и температура** стала ниже. (Я недоварил бобы потому, что, когда я их пробнул, они были мягки. Наверное, они стали тверды после того, как вода слилась (из-за чего температура стала ниже).)

Comment: А какая запятая вам нужна.